# Highlighting setting in TestComplete Code Editor

Tags: syntax-highlighting, testcomplete

What setting to change in testcomplete in order to see all the same words highlighted as the current selected one ?

I selected arrayToSearch (number 1) and i need to see the parameter of the function highlighted too (number 2).

[image]

Comment: The concept is called "Mark occurrences", but I don't think TestComplete has it.

Comment: I checked with my colleagues, and TC has this feature by default since version 12 or 13.